# How to map Contabo server to Windows 10 network drive

Tags: windows-10, ftp, sftp, centos-7

Just like the title states. I have a Contabo server but I don't want to constantly connect to the server via WinSCP.

I've tried multiple times to connect via the "Map network drive" option but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

You could install samba on your CentOS box and configure smb.conf to allow access to a shared location for the Windows system.

https://www.howtoforge.com/samba-server-installation-and-configuration-on-centos-7